# why am i unable to use pass data through my inflated layout by using share preferences?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, sharedpreferences

i have an issue regarding passing data from one class to another using intent/share preferences.

i have incremented a counter where the total is stored within the application memory using share preferences. now the total count is stored perfectly fine but when i what to pass this data to an inflated layout on my main activity, the data is then lost?

```
public class GetStartedMain{…….
public int videoCount(int totalVid){
    Toast.makeText(GetStartedMain.this, "Video was added     "+totalVid, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("VAR1", totalVid);
    editor.commit();
    int j = preferences.getInt("VAR1", 0);
    Log.e(null, "counter message @ @ @ : " + j);

    return totalVid;
} }
//then pass to ProfileVideo class

public class ProfileVideo{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile_vid_activity);
SharedPreferences preferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);

int counter = preferences.getInt("VAR1", 0); //no id: default value

Log.e(null, "counter message @ @ @ @ @ ! !: " + counter);
}
```

i have also used android intent methods where i have tried to pass the information to the inflated layouts class. this was a failure due to intent needing to start an new activity, where i want the data to to be passed to the inflated layout on my main activity.

```
public class ProfileMain{……….
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile_activity);
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", 0);

 counter = preferences.getInt("VAR1", 0); //no id: default value

Log.e(null, "counter message @ @ @ @ @: " + counter);
}
  private void buttonClickVid() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileVideo.class);
        intent.putExtra("vcount", counter);
startActivity(intent);
            mainLayer.removeAllViews();

        //showVidButton.setOnClickListener(null);
        mainLayer.addView(vidDisplay);


          //  showNoteButton.setOnClickListener(flagButton);
        }


    private void buttonClickNote() {
        mainLayer.removeAllViews();

        //showNoteButton.setOnClickListener(null);
        mainLayer.addView(noteDisplay);
        }

         // mainLayer.removeAllViews();


    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == showVidButton) {

           // buttonClickVid();
            buttonClickVid();

        }
        if (v == showNoteButton) {

            buttonClickNote();

        }

    }

—> pass to the ProfileVideo class
public class ProfileVideo extends Activity {
    TextView vidCountMain;
    int vc;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_vid_activity);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
      vc = intent.getIntExtra("vcount", 0);
        Log.e(null, "counter message @ @ @ @ @ ? vc : " + vc);

 vidCountMain=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.vid_total);
vidCountMain.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
Toast.makeText(ProfileVideo.this, "WOOOOOW   " + counter, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

i was researching and found an article saying that this is because of conflicting signatures from the main activity and the inflated layout that is layered on top of the main activity. is this true? if so how would i get around this issue?

at the moment this is what the application does
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0bfJ.jpg
--user clicks videos 
--video activity is displayed in new activity

but this is what i want it to do 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0qTa.png
--user clicks videos
--video activity is inflated onto main activity with passed results of video count

please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a new class that Has an instance of SharedPreferences, and pass to it's constructor the application Context:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;


public class ExamplePreferences {

    private SharedPreferences instancePreferences;
    private Context mContext;

    public TemperaturePreferences(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        instancePreferences= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);

    }
//Use methods to do what you need for example:
   public void putNewPreference(String key, String value) {


      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = degreesPreferences.edit();
      editor.putString(key, value);
      editor.apply();
   }

}
```

Then instantiate this class in any activity you might need it and use it. Please tell me if this works?